# How to select all records without an association? SQL

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables that I'm pulling from:

```
Company
    ID
    Code
Department
    ID
    Name 
Cost_Center
    ID
    Number
Company_Department_Cost_Center
    CompanyID
    DepartmentID
    CostCetnerID
```

There are 3 companys, 33 departments, and 25 Cost Centers.

I am designing a web form with drop downs, one for each table, that allows a user to update the Company_Department_Cost_Center table.  When the User selects the Company from the first drop down I need to filter the second two to only contain the the data in the Department table and Cost_Center table that *do not* have an existing relationship.

So if the user selects company 1, I need to select all the Departments that do not have a relationship with company 1, and subsequently all the Cost Centers without a relationship.

I'm not sure how to approach this, I'm ok with SQL but this one is eluding me.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `not exists()`, and `@CompanyId` represents your parameter.

```
select d.*
from Department d
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Company_Department_Cost_Center cdcc
  where cdcc.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    and cdcc.DepartmentId = d.Id
  )
```

And for the second query for `Cost_Center`

```
select cc.*
from Cost_Center cc
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Company_Department_Cost_Center cdcc
  where cdcc.CompanyId = @CompanyId
    and cdcc.DepartmentId = @DepartmentId
    and cdcc.CostCenterId = cc.Id
  )
```

Comment: Yes!  That's amazing.  I didn't know about "Select 1".  Thanks for your help and teaching me something!